# react i18 translate dynamic value inside the loop

Tags: reactjs, translation, i18next

I have a component that returns a JSX looped via .map(), translated for two languages 'en' & 'es'. I am using '[react i18next](https://react.i18next.com/latest/translation-render-prop)' package for this purpose.

```
const RenderInventoryItems = () =>
  inventoryList &&
  inventoryList.map(({ name, num_of_item }) => (
    <>
      <ul>
        <li>{t("inventory.item.name", name)}</Title>
        <li>{num_of_item} {t("inventory.item.num", 'pieces')}</Title>
      </ul>
    </>
  ));
```

**sample array:**

```
[
    {
        name: 'smartwatch',
        num_of_pieces: 5
    },
    {
        name: 'smart TV',
        num_of_pieces: 3
    },
    {
        name: 'juicer',
        num_of_pieces: 4
    },
    {
        name: 'hand blender',
        num_of_pieces: 10
    },
]
```

I am facing the issue that, while the variable '**`num_of_item`**' is rendered with the string '`pieces`' translated correctly in both language '`en`' & '`es`', the variable '**`name`**' is never translated to either '`en`' or '`es`'. The output is rendered with the '`name`' key repeated as it is.

*Current output (en):*

```
name
5 pieces

name
3 pieces

name
4 pieces

name
10 pieces
```

**Current output (es):**

```
name
5 piezas

name
3 piezas

name
4 piezas

name
10 piezas
```

*Expected Output (en):*

```
smartwatch
5 pieces

smart TV
3 pieces

juicer
4 pieces

blender
10 pieces
```

**Expected output (es):**

```
reloj inteligente
5 piezas

Televisión inteligente
3 piezas

exprimidor
4 piezas

licuadora
10 piezas
```

Dynamic value '`name`' is neither translated nor its value gets printed. I am new to using the `i18next` package.
Any help to resolve the same is appreciated.

Comment: You do have your translations in your application right ?

Comment: @KavinduVIndika Thanks for pointing it out. I guess it's not available for key 'name'. But how do I store the translations for the data coming from  the API ?